# Mount ecryptfs directory via SSH

Tags: encryption, ssh

I have access to a server that I use for backups. I use rsync with the --delete flag to make an exact copy of my backup directory. I have no need for incremental backups. The backup directory on the server is encrypted with ecryptfs (although not the whole home folder). I have written a script which is stored locally and executes over ssh on the server which:

1. Decrypts and mounts the directory
2. Performs rsync
3. Unmounts the directory
4. Sends me an email

The password to decrypt the directory is stored on the local machine. I am using:

```
key=passphrase:passphrase_passwd_file=/home/me/password.txt
```

in the mount command. My question is; does this pose any sort of security risk? I can't see that it does but I noted on the ecryptfs man page that using passphrase_passwd option (which I realise is different to the one above) should only be used when security is not important as the password is visible to utilities like ps. Permissions on my folder are set to 700.

Answer (score 1):

Your password can be viewed by processes in the server, since you are executing the ecryptfs there.

What you can do is to mount the ecryptfs locally. I see two options:

- Mount the server folder locally with sshfs and then ecryptfs over it.
- Reverse-mount the source folder and rsync those encrypted files to the server.

Answer (score 0):

I would Propose a different work flow for security:

- Have a Key based SSH login process. (so no passwords for that)
- Have a automated (key-based) auto mounting chroot (which is the encrypted container) and only receives the password from the SSH connection (password only leaves the client machine to unlock the ecryptfs and is protected in transit by ssh. and on site by being a simple TTY for a unprivileged user.)
- Have a different SSH session set up from the client to the now decrypted chroot in which you chroot-login.
- do your stuff
- exit the chrooted ssh session
- auto unmount the other connection (meaning you make a script that as soon as the tunnel loses focus / is closed it tries to unmount the encrypted location and keeps trying until succeeded)

I believe this setup would be the security you seek